# MathJax and latex2html5 Joomla System Plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

After reading this
[Adding Mathjax to a Joomla website](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/399/adding-mathjax-to-a-joomla-website)

I don't know anything about writing extention but based on mentioned link, I am assuming it is should be easy to write a simple system plugin to enable both mathjax and latex2html5.

I come up with this

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted index access');

class plgSystemMathJaxLatex2Html5 extends JPlugin {
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
    {   
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $doc->addScript("http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML");
            $doc->addScript(plugins/system/MathJaxLatex2Html5/assets/js/latex2html5.min.js);
            $doc->addStyleSheet(plugins/system/MathJaxLatex2Html5/assets/css/latex2html5.css);
    }
}
```

Link to the installation of latex2html5
http://latex2html5.com/installation.html

I think the only thing left now is how to include the required mathjax config into plugin.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    // <![CDATA[
    MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"]},     
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        showProcessingMessages : false,
        messageStyle : "none" ,    
        showMathMenu: false ,
        tex2jax: {
            processEnvironments: true,
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\(","\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\[","\]"] ],
            preview : "none",
            processEscapes: true
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic:true, width: "latex-container"} }
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Can anyone please guide me to the completion of the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fair play to you for deciding to use a plugin and attempt this on your own, +1.

You're very close, but forgot to use quotes when defining the path to the script and stylesheet. The following will work:

```
$doc->addScript('http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML');
$doc->addScript(JUri::root() . 'plugins/system/MathJaxLatex2Html5/assets/js/latex2html5.min.js');
$doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::root() . 'plugins/system/MathJaxLatex2Html5/assets/css/latex2html5.css');
```

Also note that for the script and stylesheet that your are importing from your own server, I have used `JUri::root()` to define the root of the your Joomla installation as a baseline.

### Update:

For to call the function, you can Joomla's `addScriptDeclaration()` function which will inject your defined script into the head and automatically use the `<script>` tags

```
$js = '
MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js"]},     
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        showProcessingMessages : false,
        messageStyle : "none" ,    
        showMathMenu: false ,
        tex2jax: {
            processEnvironments: true,
            inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\(","\)"] ],
            displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\[","\]"] ],
            preview : "none",
            processEscapes: true
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { linebreaks: { automatic:true, width: "latex-container"} }
    });
';
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the errors. I have updated the question to reflect the additional config file needed by latex2html5. Can I include those directly in the extention or I have to put it in a .js and load it through addScript?

Comment: @Starry - I have updated my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the guidance, it helps, now I don't need to manually edit template file.